# Flatten vector of enums in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to flatten a vector of `Enum` in Rust, but I am having some issues:

```
enum Foo {
    A(i32),
    B(i32, i32),
}

fn main() {
    let vf = vec![Foo::A(1), Foo::A(2), Foo::B(3, 4)];

    let vi: Vec<i32> = vf
        .iter()
        .map(|f| match f {
            Foo::A(i) => [i].into_iter(),
            Foo::B(i, j) => [i, j].into_iter(),
        })
        .collect(); // this does not compile

    // I want vi = [1, 2, 3, 4]. vf must still be valid
}
```

I could just use a regular for loop and insert elements into an existing vector, but that would be no fun. I'd like to know if there is a more idiomatic Rust way of doing it.

Comment: You could implement `IntoIterator` on `Foo` then chain iterators but honestly it's hard to make more concise or clearer than a `for` loop with a `match` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it that produces an iterator (rather than necessarily a vector, as the `fold()` based solution does).

```rust
use std::iter::once;

enum Foo {
    A(i32),
    B(i32, i32),
}

fn main() {
    let vf = vec![Foo::A(1), Foo::A(2), Foo::B(3, 4)];

    let vi: Vec<i32> = vf
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|f| {
            match f {
                &Foo::A(i) => once(i).chain(None),
                &Foo::B(i, j) => once(i).chain(Some(j)),
            }
        })
        .collect();

    dbg!(vi);
}
```

This does essentially the same thing that you were attempting, but in a way which will succeed. Here are the parts I changed, in the order they appear in the code:

1. I used [`.flat_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) instead of `.map()`. `flat_map` accepts a function which returns an *iterator* and produces the elements of that iterator ("flattening") whereas `.map()` would have just given the iterator.
2. I used `&` in the `match` patterns. This is because, since you are using `.iter()` on the vector (which is appropriate for your requirement “`vf` must still be valid”), you have references to enums, and pattern matching on a reference to an enum will normally give you references to its elements, but we almost certainly want to handle the `i32`s by value instead. There are several other things I could have done, such as using the `*` dereference operator on the values instead, but this is concise and tidy.
3. You tried to `.into_iter()` an array. Unfortunately, in current Rust this does not do what you want and you can't actually return that iterator, for somewhat awkward reasons ([which will be fixed in an upcoming Rust version](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/84147)). And then, if it *did* mean what you wanted, then you'd get an error because the two `match` arms have unequal types — one is an iterator over `[i32; 1]` and the other is an iterator over `[i32; 2]`.

   Instead, you need to build two possible iterators which are clearly of the *same* type. There are lots of ways to do this, and the way I picked was to use [`Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain) to combine [`once(i)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html), an iterator that returns the single element `i`, with an `Option<i32>` (which implements `IntoIterator`) that contains the second element `j` *if it exists*.

   Notice that in the first `match` arm I wrote the seemingly useless expression `.chain(None)`; this is so that the two arms have the same type. Another way to write the same thing, which is arguably clearer since it doesn't duplicate code that has to be identical, is:

   ```rust
   let (i, opt_j) = match f {
       &Foo::A(i) => (i, None),
       &Foo::B(i, j) => (i, Some(j)),
   };
   once(i).chain(opt_j)
   ```

   In either case, the iterator's type is `std::iter::Chain<std::iter::Once<i32>, std::option::IntoIter<i32>>` — you don't need to know this exactly, just notice that there must *be* a type which handles both the `A(i)` and the `B(i, j)` cases.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to change the `i32` references to owned values by e.g. dereferencing them. Then you can circumvent proxying through inlined arrays by using `fold()`:

```
enum Foo {
    A(i32),
    B(i32, i32),
}

fn main() {
    let vf = vec![Foo::A(1), Foo::A(2), Foo::B(3, 4)];

    let vi: Vec<i32> = vf
        .iter()
        .fold(Vec::new(), |mut acc, f| {
            match f {
                Foo::A(i) => acc.push(*i),
                Foo::B(i, j) => {
                    acc.push(*i);
                    acc.push(*j);
                }
            }
            acc
        });

}
```